# Trigger with condition on multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am currently implementing some triggers on the tables of my schema, to ensure quality of imported data.

More specifically, one column (let's call it `fraction`) is supposed to contain only percentages, i.e. values between 0 and 1 but that can sometimes be slightly above 1.

The thing is that in the original datafiles, these values are expressed as percentages, i.e. 80% for 0.8, etc.

Consequently, there is a risk that some users of the database could import data with the wrong order of magnitude, i.e. importing 70 or 80 instead of 0.7 or 0.8.

To prevent this, I have chosen the following criteria : if the **mean value** of all the rows that the user is trying to import is greater than 2, I want the software to conclude that the user has imported percentages instead of decimal values, and therefore to correct this mistake by dividing all the new values by 100.

The following `BEFORE INSERT` trigger checks, for each row, whether the value is > 2 or not, and if it is, it divides the value by 100:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost` TRIGGER `myschema`.`percentage_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `mytable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF NEW.fraction > 2
     THEN 
          SET NEW.fraction = NEW.fraction/100 ;
     END IF;
END
```

but my question is: how to have a criterion that sounds like "the mean of all the new values is > 2" instead of a criterion like "this value is > 2"?

Comment: You cannot do this in a trigger.  A trigger only looks at the inserts one row at a time.  You need to pre-process the file to determine what to do -- or better yet, load the data into a staging table and do this work when you copy the data over to the real table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the reply. That's unfortunate. I wish the users of my database could directly import their raw data into the DB using the mySQL for Excel plugin, but it looks like they will still have to perform intermediate calculations in Excel before using the import plugin...